# Unit conversion errors for value objects in ddd

Tags: domain-driven-design

As you might know DDD literature suggests that we should treat " numeric quantativies with some unit " as value objects, not as primitive types ( ints, bigdecimal ). Some examples of such value objects are money, distance or file size. I agree with the big picture

However there is something I cannot understand. Namely conversion errors when representating something in one unit, converting it to other unit and back. This process might lose some information. Take for example file size. Lets say I have file whose size is 3.67 MB and I convert that to other instance of FileSize whose unit would be GB by dividing 3.67 with 1024. Now I have FileSize of ( approximately ) 0.00358398437 GB. If I now try to convert it back to MB the result is not 3.67 MB. If however I dont use value object but instead only use primitive information " sizeInBytes " ( long ) I cannot lose information on conversion errors.

I must have missed something. Is my example just plain stupid? Or is it acceptable to lose some info when converting from one unit to another? Or should FileSize always carry also excat file size in bytes ( with approx.size in given unit )?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is more an implementation problem of your concrete example than a problem with the approach. The idea of using value objects to represent amounts with a unit is to avoid mistakes like adding Liters to Kilometers or doing 10cm + 10Km = 20cm. Value objects, when developed correctly, will enforce that the operations are done correctly between different units.

Now, how you implement these value objects with your programming language, is a different problem. But for your concrete example, I would say that the value object will internally have a `long` field with the size in Bytes, no matter what unit you use to initialize the object. In this case, the unit will be used to convert the initialization value to the right amount of bytes and also for display purposes, but when you have to add 2 FileSizes, you can add the internal amounts in bytes.

Comment: Thanks. There is still one problem storing Bytes as long. Lets say I support static constructor megaBytes (Bigdecimal value) and pass 3.67 as parameter. Converting that to Bytes (3.97*1024*1024) results to 3848274.92. Would that be 3848272 or 3848273 or should the static constructor only support integer parameter (rendering it bit useless)

Comment: You (or your stakeholders) need to decide based on your business needs. IMO, if a user enters 3.67MB, she doesn't care about an error of a fraction of a byte. I would just round it and it will still be 3.67MB. If, on the other hand, exact precision to the byte is necessary, then you simply cannot initialise the value this way. Maybe instead of a static factory, you need something more complex, eg define an interface IProvideStandardDiskSizes or whatever your domain requires.

Answer (score 2):

> we should treat " numeric quantativies with some unit " as value objects, not as primitive types ( ints, bigdecimal ).

Yes, that's right.  More generally, we're encouraged to encapsulate data structures (an integer alone is a trivially simple data structure) behind domain specific abstractions.  This is one good way to leverage type checking - it gives the checker the hints that it needs to detect a category of dumb mistakes.

> Namely conversion errors when representating something in one unit, converting it to other unit and back. This process might lose some information.

That's right.  More generally: *rounding* loses information.

> I dont use value object but instead only use primitive information " sizeInBytes " ( long ) I cannot lose information on conversion errors.

So look carefully at that: if you perform the same sequence of conversions you described using primitive data structures, you would end up with the same rounding error (after all, that's where the rounding error came from: the abstraction of the measurement defers the calculation to its internal general purpose representation).

The thing that saves you from the error is not discarding the original exact answer.

What domain modeling is telling you to do is make explicit which values are "exact" and which have "rounding errors".

(Note that in some domains, they aren't even "errors"; many domains have explicit rules about how rounding is supposed to happen.  Sadly, they are rarely the rounding rules defined by IEEE-754, so you can't just lean on the general purpose floating point type.)

DDD will also encourage you to track precisely which values are for display/reporting, and which are to be used in later calculations.

Comment: Thanks. What I ment with using primitive data (instead of VO) and not losing info on conversion (back & worth)was that I would have long field sizeInBytes declared on the entity instead of fileSize (VO) and then I would have method getSizeInMb on entity which would return BigDecimal instead of VO FileSize which would have method toMb which would return FileSize (thus prone to conversion errors when converting back & worth).If I understand correctly u are suggesting that I should have FileSize and RoundedFileSize VOs and FileSize:toMb would return RoundedFileSize?

Answer (score 1):

Reading this, I think you're misunderstanding what DDD is.  The first D is DDD, stands for Domain - aka Domain is a sphere of knowledge.  The way you represent a sphere of knowledge aka a Domain - is entirely based on the business domain you're attempting to represent, and will be different based on the business domain.

So...
Domain A: Business User that has X amount of storage space

- I upload X file
- file X uses 3.67 MB
- You have used 1% of your allocated space.
- You have 97 MB space remaining

Domain B: Sys Admin - total space is Y amount of storage space

- Users have uploaded 3.67 MB
- That user has used 1% of their space
- That user has 97 MB space remaining
- There is 1000 GB total space remaining to allocate to all users / total space remaining.

aka. Sys Admin has one domain - total disk; User has allocated space (sub-set) - they have different domains of knowledge - space.

Also note... DDD is really about sectioning of a domain or sphere of knowledge to the specific users of sub-sections of a system - and not the facts of a system. aka Facts are different from knowledge.

I hope this makes some sense!

Comment: I'll just add one more comment - how far away is the sun from the earth.. is it 152 million km; or is it 149,600,000? Or is it 149,600,123?  Or 149,600,123.143284723472331273404732047324723984732984734723894123? It depends on precision, or interpretation

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you are saying. It is more like "big picture" and really about what the business is all about. But still I would like to have my conversions done "right" (devil is in the details)